# Is there a way to include a variable in a path to another variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to use a package.json to store variables in multiple 'folders,' like so:

```
"servers": {
    "folder1": {
        "modrole": "Moderator"
    },
    "folder2": {
        "modrole": "bot owner"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to replace the folder specification with a variable:

```
var foldername = 'folder1'
package.servers.[value of foldername].modrole
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable inside the brackets.

```js
const package = {
  "servers": {
    "folder1": {
      "modrole": "Moderator"
    },
    "folder2": {
      "modrole": "bot owner"
    }
  }
}
let folderName = "folder1"
console.log(package.servers[folderName].modrole)
```